# What CSS specificity rule is causing the problem I'm seeing?

Tags: html, css

I've got a left-hand border on items in a list, and for all of them I set the `border-left-color` to transparent. The active item, denoted by a css class "active day" gets an actual color to its border. The code looks something like this (note I've omitted irrelevant styles):

```
<!-- example.html -->

<div id="day-sidebar">
    <div class="active-day">
        <h2>19</h2>
        <p>Fri</p>
    </div>                
    <div>
        <h2>20</h2>
        <p>Sat</p>
    </div>                
    <div>
        <h2>21</h2>
        <p>Sun</p>
    </div>                
</div>
```

```
/* example.css */

#day-sidebar div {
    border-left-width: 15px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}

.active-day {
    border-left-color: red;
}
```

My understanding is:

- Classes take higher precedence than tags
- Within a CSS file, rules later in the file take precedence to rules earlier in the file

Yet my first `div` in this example does not take on the new border color for `active-day`. Why is this?

Note: It works when I add `!important` to the CSS, but I understand that should only be used as a final measure.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the problem! Even though I'm selecting `divs` in my first CSS rule, the fact that I'm using an HTML id to denote the parent element makes that whole rule take the precedence of IDs, which are above classes. A way to make this work would be to give each div a class of "day" like so:

```
<!-- example.html -->

<div id="day-sidebar">
    <div class="day active-day">
        <h2>19</h2>
        <p>Fri</p>
    </div>                
    <div class="day">
        <h2>20</h2>
        <p>Sat</p>
    </div>                
    <div class="day">
        <h2>21</h2>
        <p>Sun</p>
    </div>                
</div>
```

```
/* example.css */

.day {
    border-left-width: 15px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}

.active-day {
    border-left-color: red;
}
```

Comment: And you can also read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity to understand the hierarchy.

Comment: Oh great you figured it out. My answer is now redundant :P

Comment: lol @ralphwayTOW sorry about that! Thanks for the answer nevertheless. I guess more selectors = more specificity? I've still learned something new.

Comment: No worries man. But yea, you are totally right: the more selectors, the higher the priority. :) This is something also touched on in the mozilla post , that @A.Meshu posted - worth a read!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specified:

```
#day-sidebar div {
    border-left-width: 15px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

The styles in this will be priorities higher than using just `.active-day`. There simply are more selectors, and therefore higher priority. Also the id gives higher priority than a class.

You could solve this with doing the following:

```
.active-day {
    border-left-color: red !important;
}
```

However I would (and you should) do the following:

```
#day-sidebar .active-day {
    border-left-color: red;
}
```

Using `!important` isn't recommended - only use ´!important´ when necessary.

Let me know if it helps :)